# How to raise event for buttons which are created dynamically in DCL.loadintolocation()?

Tags: typescript, angular

Hi i am trying to load a component using DCL loadintolocation().The component is loading perfectly but i want to raise an event from the buttons that are created dynamically.I made a demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/PFOFyd9XN5xMzwK9q0fP?p=preview  > I want to raise the event for button with name "destroy". Somebody please help me how to bind the event for buttons that are created dynamically.

```
add(){
this.renderTemplate(`
  <div id="evnt">
  <button (click)="raiseevent()">Destroy</button>
    <some-component></some-component>
  </div>
`, [SomeComponent]);
```

}

```
raiseevent(){
alert('hi');
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the `raiseevent` method that is called should be in the component you dynamically added. In your case it's in the component that creates it.

If you do this, the raiseevent method is called:

```
function toComponent(template, directives) {
  @Component({ 
    selector: 'fake-component',
    template,directives
  })

  class FakeComponent {
    a:any;
    dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
    public fakeForm: ControlGroup;
    public items: QueryList<SomeComponent>;

    constructor(@ViewQuery(SomeComponent) 
           items:QueryList<SomeComponent>) {
      this.items = items;
    }

    raiseevent(){
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
  return FakeComponent;
}
```

If you want to call the `raiseevent` method from the parent component, you can refactor your `FakeComponent` as described below. This shows how to inject this parent component and use its methods.

```
function toComponent(template, directives) {
  @Component({ 
    selector: 'fake-component',
    template,directives
  })

  class FakeComponent {
    a:any;
    dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
    public fakeForm: ControlGroup;
    public items: QueryList<SomeComponent>;

    constructor(@ViewQuery(SomeComponent) 
          items:QueryList<SomeComponent>,
          private comp: AppComponent) {
      this.items = items;
    }
  }
  return FakeComponent;
}
```

Here is the new content of the template:

```
add() {
  this.renderTemplate(`
    <div id="evnt">
      <button (click)="comp.raiseevent()">Destro</button>
      <some-component></some-component>
    </div>
  `, [SomeComponent]);
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I am trying to pass the argument...When the button is clicked i am trying to dispose that component...I am sending ref as argument but it is showing some error...How should i pass the argument and dispose that component (i need to remove button also)?

Comment: I think that it's a similar problem because `this.b` is parent of the parent component and not the child one... I would be interested in having the error you have...

Comment: yea...tried many ways but not successful. Is there anyway i can pass ref as argument?

Comment: Got the result in desired way by setting the property of ref...here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/PFOFyd9XN5xMzwK9q0fP?p=preview  .Is this a correct approach?